# How to make pf4j plugin beans injectable into Spring app

Tags: spring-boot, pf4j

We are trying to utilize pf4j and pf4j-spring to provide a flexible application based on Spring.

Ideally, we would like to define Spring beans (`@Service`, `@Repository` and others) in plugins and inject them in the main application.

From what I can see, it seems to fail due to timing issues. Or in other words, Springs expects the beans to be available before the `PluginManager` gets instantiated.

There is an example repository that illustrates the issue [on GitHub](https://github.com/daincredibleholg/pf4j-spring-issues).

The question would be: Can I change something, so that Spring instantiates the `PluginManager` first? Is there another approach to make this work?

Note: Yes, we are aware of [sbp](https://github.com/hank-cp/sbp). Unfortunately, it seems to be dead, and we didn't get it working properly either.

Comment: Despite I do not have an answer for you, I am interested in how are you expecting that your component scan search for the classes on the plugins that have the `@Component` and others annotations. Because the idea of plugins is to not enforce, for example, the package structure.

Comment: hey @incredibleholg, I am the author of sbp, and I am not dead yet :) If you have any problem, welcome to post issue on github.